# Unable to load solution created in VS for Mac in Xamarin Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I am testing out the new **Visual Studio for Mac**, and I created a new .NET Core empty web application - was able to build and run the project.

Then I tried opening the solution with Xamarin Studio and I got the following error message:

`Project file doesn't have a valid ProjectGuid`

Am I trying to do something that is not possible at the moment, or am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Do you have the .net core add in installed?  https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin

Comment: I installed the addin, Xamarin Studio freezes when opening the solution... No error pop up. I think I'll wait for the next update. Thanks for taking your time to answer.

Comment: Maybe you will have a better experience with visual studio for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Studio does not support .NET Core projects created by Visual Studio for Mac.

The project file format is very different for .NET Core projects created by Visual Studio for Mac. One example is that the project does not have a GUID however there are many differences.

The DNX addin was created to support the older style .NET Core projects, which use .xproj and project.json files. Visual Studio for Mac creates the newer MSBuild SDK style project files which are .csproj files.